# How do i run mutiple commands on an else: statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, command

i was coding some python and ran into a problem where it only lets me run one command for an else: statement
here in this i have to indent all the state after print(" ") and the it will run after g when i want it to run just with else:

```
question = input('Is The Bee Movie Good Or Bad (g/b)')
if question == "g":
  print(" ")
  print("Good")
else:
  print(" ")
 import time
 time.sleep(1)
 print(".")
 import time
 time.sleep(.5)
 print(".")
 import time
 time.sleep(.5)
 print(".")
 import time
 time.sleep(.5)
 print(".")
 import time
 time.sleep(.5)
 print(".")
 import time
 time.sleep(.1)
 for i in range(50):
 print("Error, System Shutdown Active")
```

Comment: Hint: Whitespace is significant in Python. Does the first line of code in your `else` block look different from the rest?

Comment: Indentation, one space difference...

Comment: Just indent them (with one space), to be at the same level as the 1st instruction that comes after `else` (`print(" ")`).

Comment: Also, why in the world do you keep importing `time`?

Comment: to put delay inbetween everything

Comment: @James You only need to import `time` once, and after that you can use it how many times you want.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  You might also work through a tutorial on Python syntax, as you have multiple problems in this posting.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified demonstration of your problem, with just two prints in `then` and in `else` of the `if`? I.e. no importing, no time, fewer lines, double checked white space.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentaion is off, everything to be done for `else` needs to be on the same indentation level.

Idented by two " ":

```
else:
  print(" ")
```

only one " ":

```
 time.sleep(1)
```

Also, do your importing once at the start of the code, not repeatedly.

```
# start of program
import time
```

Comment: yes well when i put it on the same indentation level it wont run until i unindent it

Comment: Do you mean that the first statement `print(" ")` is not executed and all others either, if you do e.g. `if answer == "never ever"`? I.e. are you sure that the non-execution is not caused by the if being true? And you tried this again after cleaning up the importing strangeness?

Comment: i mean when i put the code on the same level as the print(" ") it comes up with an error message and wont run it unless i put it to what it is that i showed u. but then when i run it everything past print(" ") runs with if question == "g"

Comment: The code you show gives me the error message "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" for the second line after `else:`.

Comment: i get :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you please make a [mcve], with only two prints each in the branches of the `if`? And please type that from scratch, paying attention to each letter and whitespace typed. Make sure that you do not have any strange (Unicode) versions of letters or whitespace. And much shorter, without additional complication by `import` etc.

Comment: Bee careful not to mix blank/space/" " with tab/"\t" when copying to StackOverflow.